# Adding custom features to Stanford NER without touching the source code

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-classification

I have added custom features to my Stanford NER model as suggested in the following link:

[Stanford-NER customization to classify software programming keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950995/stanford-ner-customization-to-classify-software-programming-keywords)

I was wondering, Is there any better approach at this movement to add custom features without modifying source code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something similar to the question you referenced, you might just want to use RegexNER to add custom NER tags:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner/

Please let me know if you need to customize anything else!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was looking to add some other types of custom features. e.g:- Stanford NER has feature "use2W". What if I want to add similar feature say "use3W". Is there any way I can add it without having to modify SeqClassifierFlags & NERFeatureFactory classes?